# rSymPy solve symbolic equation with substituted defined variables

Tags: r, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the code below that I am trying to solve with `rSymPy`. All of the variables in the equation are defined below, except for `y` -- which I am solving for.

How can I substitute the values for `Q`, `n`, `m`, `g`, `k`, and `Sf` simultaneously in the equation defined below and obtain the value of `y`?

```
Q <- 1.2
n <- 0.045
m <- 3.4
g <- 9.806
k <- 1
Sf <- 0.2

library(rSymPy)
sympy("solve( [ Eq(n*Q*(2*y*sqrt(1+m**2))**(2/3) - k*(m*y**2)** 
(5/3)*sqrt(Sf), 0)], [y] )")
```

This is the error that I received from the function call:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't you need `sympy` to also create the variables?

Comment: @Pascal   Thank you for your suggestion. I went back to the SymPy Tutorial and worked on more examples until I could find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following is the solution that I have come up with:

```
library(rSymPy)
Q <- Var("Q")
n <- Var("n")
m <- Var("m")
g <- Var("g")
k <- Var("k")
Sf <- Var("Sf")
y <- Var("y")

sympy("expr = n*Q*(2*y*sqrt(1+m**2))**(2/3) - k*(m*y**2)**(5/3)*sqrt(Sf)")
# [1] "Q*n - k*m*Sf**(1/2)*y**2"

sympy("solve(expr.subs([(Q, 1.2), (n, 0.045), (m, 3.4), (Sf, 0.2), (g, 9.806), (k, 1)]), y)")
# [1] "[-0.188451640531767, 0.188451640531767]"
# This is the answer that I am referring to (above)

out <- sympy("solve(expr.subs([(Q, 1.2), (n, 0.045), (m, 3.4), (Sf, 0.2), (g, 9.806), (k, 1)]), y)")
out <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", out), ",")))
length(out)
# [1] 2
out
# [1] -0.1884516  0.1884516
```

Comment: Better to avoid new question in answer.

Comment: @Pascal  Thank you for the answer. Next time I'll ask a separate question in a separate posting.

Comment: Please don't break the lines in your code. If you introduce break, `sympy` throws error.

Comment: @Pascal  Ok, thank you for letting me know. I introduced the breaks to improve the formatting only.

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice. But in the case of `sympy`, it seems to break the function.